# Footprints in the Sands of Time?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm searching for a sci-fi short story. Back in about 1978, I read a story I'd swear was called "Footprints in the Sands of Time." I'm pretty sure it was written earlier, since it was in a class on classic science fiction. I think it was in a collection of short stories too. I've googled this and similar titles, but no luck.

The plot involves someone going back in time and leaving a capsule of radium behind to prove they made the trip. Time was described as a "coiled spring," where the successive turns were separated by 60 million years (I think).

Comment: Reminds me of a quote by Jo Ryan: "You can't leave footprints in the sands of time if you're sitting on your butt. And who wants to leave buttprints in the sands of time?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is P. Schuyler Miller's "The Sands of Time", published in *Astounding Stories*, 1937

[This link](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2011/01/p-schuyler-miller-sands-of-time-novella.html), provides information that matches one of your clues:

> A young man travels back to dinosaur era, & brings back souvenirs to prove it. He even buries a lead box containing radium in that period so someone can dig it out today as ultimate proof of his visit!

If this is the right answer, it's a [duplicate of this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192441/time-traveler-asks-archaeologist-for-help-in-transporting-a-girl-from-dinosaur-e) If you read the answer there, you'll see that the story does indeed refer to time as "coiled".

[According to its ISFDB page,](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48004) it's been published in a few anthologies over the years, any of which could be where you read it.

Comment: I don't think the other counts as a duplicate as the details remembered are significantly different.  Two questions can have the same answer and not be duplicate questions

Comment: @Kevin Our [policy on story-id dupe-closing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028) is to close as duplicates (with the more complete Q/A as the target) when both have accepted (through checkmark or comment) the same work.

Comment: @Jenayah I think that's kind of silly, but if that's the policy then I guess this is a duplicate

Comment: @Kevin dupe-closing isn't a punition. On the contrary, it might point future readers to more details on a work they're looking for, and keeps the story-id Qs together :) (we still have to wait for OP's acceptance on that one, though)

Comment: @Kevin The policy is fairly consistent with the [intended usage](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) of duplicate closing. The idea is that it funnels people who use different search strategies toward the info they all need and provides us Stack Exchangians a central location to curate the content.

Comment: @jpmc26 I guess that makes sense.  Just seems odd.  Kind of like saying 3+3 is a duplicate of square root of 36.  They have the same answer, but are very different problems

Comment: @Kevin No, they have much more in common than different. Both askers are looking for a story they can't identify. The half remembered details are *similar*, but not quite exactly the same. Each probably has some details the other doesn't, and it turns out they were looking for the same story. And in practice, giving others more details to consider only increases the likelihood that they don't need to ask a new question.

Comment: @jpmc26 The details are very different.  Only thing they have in common is time travel, which is hardly uncommon in sci-fi stories